# .Net Core and IdentityServer4 using https in the Authority option fails

Tags: authentication, https, .net-core, identityserver4

In my Startup.cs ConfigureServices method I have:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = applicationUrl;
                options.SupportedTokens = SupportedTokens.Jwt;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; // Note: Set to true in production
                options.ApiName = IdentityServerConfig.ApiName;
            });
```

I am able to get an access_token... but then I get a 401 unauthorized when I try to access "/users/me".

where applicationUrl is something like "https://myapi.mysite.com"

but if I change:

```
                options.Authority = applicationUrl;
```

to:

```
                options.Authority = applicationUrl.Replace("https", "http");
```

it works.

I don't know why an https url is a problem... I am able to access my entire site with https. Also, setting RequireHttpsMetadata = true doesn't help.

thoughts?

BTW, my AddIdentityServer looks like this:

```
        services.AddIdentityServer()
          // The AddDeveloperSigningCredential extension creates temporary key material for signing tokens.
          // This might be useful to get started, but needs to be replaced by some persistent key material for production scenarios.
          // See http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/crypto.html#refcrypto for more information.
          // .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
          .AddSigningCredential(certificate)
          .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
          {
              options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
          })
          .AddOperationalStore(options =>
          {
              options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

              // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional. 
              options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
              options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30;
          })
          .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
          .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that `Authority` has to be equal to the `Issuer`. This allows the client / resource to verify that the creator of the token is indeed the trusted authority.

You can see the actual value of issuer in `https://ids4.mysite.com/.well-known/openid-configuration`.

`IssuerUri` can optionally be set in the [IdentityServer configuration](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/options.html):

> Set the issuer name that will appear in the discovery document and the
>   issued JWT tokens. It is recommended to not set this property, which
>   infers the issuer name from the host name that is used by the clients.